# Script Editor won't open or change language in SSIS 2005

Tags: ssis, bids, ssis-2005

I have a task which creates a SSIS package using BIDS 2005. There are 2 problems when I work with BIDS 2005, but don't occur in BIDS 2008.

1. Default language in Script Editor is Visual Basic (I prefer C#).
2. When I click on the <kbd>Design Script</kbd> button, it closes current Script Task Editor and nothing happens.

My personal ideas are:

1. SSIS 2005 doesn't support C# version to write custom code
2. Bug in BIDS

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. SSIS 2005 only supports VB.NET (*not* C#) within Script Task or Script Component.
2. Make sure that you have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 installed on the machine that has BIDS. If not, [download Service Pack 3 here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14752) and install it.

Comment: I installed SP4 and that fixed the Design Script button
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7218